# numpy convert categorical string arrays to an integer array

Tags: python, statistics, numpy, machine-learning

I'm trying to convert a string array of categorical variables to an integer array of categorical variables.

Ex.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array( ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
print a.dtype
>>> |S1

b = np.unique(a)
print b
>>>  ['a' 'b' 'c']

c = a.desired_function(b)
print c, c.dtype
>>> [1,2,3,1,2,3] int32
```

I realize this can be done with a loop but I imagine there is an easier way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a hack... but does it help?

```
In [72]: c=(a.view(np.ubyte)-96).astype('int32')

In [73]: print(c,c.dtype)
(array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]), dtype('int32'))
```

Comment: You seriously want to add the caveat that this only works for length-1 strings.

Answer (score 71):

np.unique has some optional returns

return_inverse gives the integer encoding, which I use very often

```
>>> b, c = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
>>> b
array(['a', 'b', 'c'], 
      dtype='|S1')
>>> c
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
>>> c+1
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
```

it can be used to recreate the original array from uniques

```
>>> b[c]
array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 
      dtype='|S1')
>>> (b[c] == a).all()
True
```

Answer (score 37):

... years later....

For completeness (because this isn't mentioned in the answers) and personal reasons (I *always* have `pandas` imported in my modules but not necessarily `sklearn`), this is also quite straightforward with `pandas.get_dummies()`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas

In [1]: a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'])

In [2]: b = pandas.get_dummies(a)

In [3]: b
Out[3]: 
      a  b  c
   0  1  0  0
   1  0  1  0
   2  0  0  1
   3  1  0  0
   4  0  1  0
   5  0  0  1

In [3]: b.values.argmax(1)
Out[4]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks. Finally found the answer which I'm looking for.

Answer (score 19):

One way is to use the [`categorical`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.tools.tools.categorical.html) function from [scikits.statsmodels](http://scikits.appspot.com/statsmodels).  For example:

```
In [60]: from scikits.statsmodels.tools import categorical

In [61]: a = np.array( ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'])

In [62]: b = categorical(a, drop=True)

In [63]: b.argmax(1)
Out[63]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

The return value from `categorical` (`b`) is actually a design matrix, hence the call to `argmax` above to get it close to your desired format.

```
In [64]: b
Out[64]:
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use a categorical pandas Series:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'], dtype="category").cat.codes.values

array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int8)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use [sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn-preprocessing-labelencoder)

It can convert hashable labels like strings to numerical values ranging between 0 and `n_classes-1`.

It is done like this:

```py
# Repeating setup from the question to make example copy/paste-able
import numpy as np
a = np.array( ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
b = np.unique(a)

# Answer to the question
from sklearn import preprocessing
pre = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
pre.fit(b)
c = pre.transform(a)

print(c)    # Prints [0 1 2 0 1 2]
```

If you insist on having the values start from 1 in the resulting array you could simply do `c + 1` afterwards.

It might not be worth it to bring in sklearn as a dependency for a project only to do this, but it is a good option if you have sklearn already imported.

Comment: How can we can we know that 'a' is '0' and so on. There is any code that can return such that?

Comment: @bib: I believe a new running number/index is allocated every time a new string is encountered while traversing the array from left to right. So `'a'` is `0` because it was the first string that was seen.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use Pandas `factorize` to map items to a number:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
In [4]: a_enc = pd.factorize(a)
In [5]: a_enc[0]
Out[5]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
In [6]: a_enc[1]
Out[6]: array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

...some more years pass...

Thought I would provide a pure python solution for completeness:

```
def count_unique(a):
    def counter(item, c=[0], items={}):
        if item not in items:
            items[item] = c[0]
            c[0] += 1
        return items[item]
    return map(counter, a)

a = [0, 2, 6, 0, 2]
print count_unique(a)
>> [0, 1, 2, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

```
a = np.array( ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
a[a == 'a'] = 1
a[a == 'b'] = 2
a[a == 'c'] = 3
a = a.astype(np.float32)
```

It would be better if you know what's in there and wish to set specific index for each values.

If there's only two categories, next code will work like a charm:

```
a = np.array( ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'])
a = np.float32(y == 'a')
```