# Numpy : convert labels into indexes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, classification, data-science

Is it possible to convert a string vector into an indexed one using `numpy` ?

Suppose I have an array of strings like `['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'DEF', 'ABC']` etc. I want it to be changed to an array of integers like `[0,1,2,1,0]`. Is it possible using numpy? I know that `Pandas` has a `Series` class that can do this, courtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37122326/8507120). Is there something similar for `numpy` as well?

Edit : 
 `np.unique()` returns unique value for all elements. What I'm trying to do is convert the labels in the [Iris dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/iris/data) to indices, such as 0 for `Iris-setosa`, 1 for `Iris-versicolor` and 2 for `Iris-virginica` respectively. Is there a way to do this using `numpy`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with parameter `return_inverse=True`, but there is difference with handling `NaN`s - check [factorizing values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#factorizing-values):

```
L = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'DEF', 'ABC']

print (np.unique(L, return_inverse=True)[1])
[0 1 2 1 0]
```

pandas [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) working nice with list or array too:

```
print (pd.factorize(L)[0])
[0 1 2 1 0]
```