# I have a categorical numpy array , want to convert it into integer?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I have a data set like `education{primary,graduate}`, `martial status{male,female}`, `job{employed, service,unemployed}` . This is categorical data set I want to convert it into float for logistic regression in numpy python.

Comment: Small note: I don't think "service" and "unemployed" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Its an example . The thing is that i want to convert all into float/Int data type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy convert categorical string arrays to an integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172509/numpy-convert-categorical-string-arrays-to-an-integer-array)

Answer (score 1):

One option wold be creating a dictionary and applying it in a list comprehension like:

```
education = {'primary':0, 'graduate':1}
ed_data = ['primary', 'primary', 'graduate', 'primary', 'graduate']

num_ed_data = [educaiton[i] for i in ed_data]
# Output: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```