# How to create a list of labels for a list of items?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, numpy

I wonder if the following can be done better:

```
import numpy as np
def label_items(items):
    data = np.array(items)
    labels = np.zeros(len(items), dtype='int')
    for label, value in enumerate(set(items)):
        labels[data==value] = label
    return labels
```

for example:

```
label_items(['a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'e', 'e', 'd', 'c'])
```

will return

```
array([0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1])
```

Addendum: the letters are merely an example, it could be a list of anything. That's why I called the function "label_items". The order of the labels doesn't matter.

Comment: So your data will always be in this form with "clear" mapping from letter to number?

Comment: The letters are just an example, it could be a list of anything really.

Comment: How would you determine what 'label' to give them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy convert categorical string arrays to an integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172509/numpy-convert-categorical-string-arrays-to-an-integer-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If order is not important, you can use [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
import numpy as np

def label_items(arr):
    return np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)

vals, labels = label_items(['a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'e', 'e', 'd', 'c'])

print(vals)

['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e']

print(labels)

[0 0 2 3 4 1 4 4 3 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use simple `map`:

```
list(map(lambda x: ord(x) - ord('a'), a))
```

Result:

```
[0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 2]
```

So, [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) function returns an integer representing the Unicode code point of that character. Than `ord(x) - ord('a')`, where `x` - some letter, returns alphabetical order number.

Comment: It'll be helpful if you could explain what you did.

Comment: The letters where just an example, it should work for other stuff as well