# Creating a list of strings defined by similar items in a `numpy.array`

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

**Given:**

- list of strings:

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'grey', 'black', 'yellow', 'brown', 'orange', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'teal', 'turquise']
```

- `a`, a `numpy.array` with `a.shape[0]` <= `len(colors)` that contains some numeric (repeating) values.

**Requirement:**

Producing a list `l`, of `str` objects that will match the elements in `a`. I.e. for each element in `a`, there will be the same `str` object in `l`, as in shown in `Example 1`.

**Example 1:**

Given:

```
import numpy as np


colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'grey', 'black', 'yellow', 'brown', 'orange', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'teal', 'turquise']

a = np.array([0, 1, 5, 7, 1, 5, 7, 7, 0, 0])
```

the desired output should be:

```
Out: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'grey', 'blue', 'green', 'grey', 'grey', 'red', 'red']
```

**My solution:**

I can think of two ways to do it as shown in `Code 1` and `Code 2`.

**Code 1:**

```
import numpy as np

colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'grey', 'black', 'yellow', 'brown', 'orange', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'teal', 'turquise']
a = np.array([0, 1, 5, 7, 1, 5, 7, 7, 0, 0])

num_2_color_dict = {}
for num in np.unique(a):
    num_2_color_dict[num] = colors[np.min(np.where(a==num))]
    
color_by_num = []
for num in a:
    color_by_num.append(num_2_color_dict[num])
color_by_num
```

```
Out: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'grey', 'blue', 'green', 'grey', 'grey', 'red', 'red']
```

**Code 2:**

```
import numpy as np

colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'grey', 'black', 'yellow', 'brown', 'orange', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'teal', 'turquise']
a = np.array([0, 1, 5, 7, 1, 5, 7, 7, 0, 0])

colors_by_num = [colors[np.min(np.where(np.unique(a)==num))] for num in a]
colors_by_num
```

**Question:**

I'd like to be able to achieve the same result without using loops, and preferably with some `numpy` array manipulation technique, that will shorten the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Josef states in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172509/numpy-convert-categorical-string-arrays-to-an-integer-array), numpy.unique has the option to return integer encodings, which is what you want. So the following piece of code should help you out:

```
np.take(colors, np.unique(a,return_inverse=True)[1])
```

With setting `return_inverse=True`, you get the integer encodings, as second return parameter. `Numpy.take()` gives you the items for the indices.

Answer (score 1):

```
colors = np.array(['red', 'blue', 'green', 'grey', 'black', 'yellow', 'brown', 'orange', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'teal', 'turquise'])
a      = np.array([0, 1, 5, 7, 1, 5, 7, 7, 0, 0])

_, i = np.where(a[:, None] == np.unique(a))

colors[i]


>>> array(['red', 'blue', 'green', 'grey', 'blue', 'green', 'grey', 'grey', 'red', 'red'])
```